# Xcode login Managed Google Workspace account

Tags: xcode, google-workspace, apple-id

I can't login to Xcode for signing anymore now that my dev account was transfered to a managed Google Workspace account. Any idea how i can login, Xcode says it doesnt recognize the E-Mail as an Apple-ID anymore, eventough i can login through appstoreconnect with Google SSO...